Proof of Non-Exactness for Polynomials of Degree p in Quadrature Formulas
Given a Quadrature Rule
$$ \int_{a}^{b} f(x)dx \approx (b-a) \sum_{k=1}^s b_k f(a+c_k(b-a))$$
of order $p$
$$\frac{1}{q} = \sum_{k=1}^s b_k^{q-1} for\:all\: q=1,...,p\:, but\:not\:q=p+1$$
Show that the quadrature Rule can't approximate a polynomial of degree $p$ exactly
There is the hint that I should use
$$f(x)=a_p \left(\frac{x-a}{b-a}\right)^p + g(x),\: a_p \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\},\: g(x) \in \mathbb{P}_{p-1}$$
Any help is appreciated
